# template with large left margin and coloured box

Tags: beamer, templates

I'm building for my university a template using the Latex beamer package.

I had no problems to build the template for the title slide and for the general slides. However, for the last slide they would like a template that looks as in the image attached.

It seems to me to be very simple, but I have not found a way to create just this empty blue box (that should not have any effect on the other parts of the slide) and have the text start with quite a large left margin (I would like to create this as a template and not have the user adjust the margin for the last slide in his document).

Could you give me hints on how to realise this?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to adjust the numbers according to the geometry and margins you use for your template

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=254mm,paperheight=190.5mm,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm} 
\setbeamersize{text margin left=17.4mm,text margin right=10.6mm}

\newcommand{\myendpage}[1]{
    \begin{frame}[plain]
       \setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
        \begin{picture}(254,190.5)(17.4,0)
            \put(0,0){\color{blue}\rule{.5\paperwidth}{200mm}}
            \put(140,110.7){%
                \begin{minipage}[b][45mm][t]{226mm}
                \usebeamerfont{title}{\raggedright {#1} \par}
                \end{minipage}
            }   
        \end{picture}
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
    \myendpage{test \\[1cm] test \\[1cm] test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works pretty well. I replaced what you do with picture, by using a beamercolorbox, but otherwise it's pretty much the same.

Comment: Perhaps you want to post your simpler solution. It could be interesting for other people.